# git apply -v, does it return anything when it has been patched successfully?

Tags: git, drupal

I'm trying to patch a module for my project, so I just followed what everyone suggested, download the patch to the particular module folder, do the *git apply -v xxx.patch* to the contributed module, but it didn't return anything once I do that, is that normal? Or it will return something like *patches successfully*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my own question, for some reason, `patch -p1 < xxx.patch` works for me.
Stated at the footnotes #2 of http://drupal.org/node/1054616
After that input `git diff HEAD^ | mate`, Hooray! Thanks @Jan for helping out though.

Answer (score 2):

Check the return code. If it's 0 then it's successful.

```
git apply -v some.patch
echo $?
```

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-apply) doesn't specify what the actual output for a successful action should be.

Comment: but if I do the git diff it wouldn't show me the changes, even if I open up the xxx.patch and compare with the xxx.module, it also doesn't seems to be updated, although it's returning 0 when I input echo $?

Comment: See `git log` and `git show`. Do they show your patch applied?

Comment: Does "show nothing" mean "there's no Git history at all"? Are you executing these commands in a Git repository? Could you tell us more about symptoms you're seeing?

Comment: Sorry for didn't say it properly. If `git log`, it showing the previous commits that I've made, with the commit message. If `git show`, it showing the changes, which I update the module.

Comment: You can do this `git apply --check -v some.patch` (add the `--check` flag) before you actually try to apply the patch. Can you give me a link to the patch so I can have a look on my machine, maybe there's something wrong with the patch but git should give some feedback. That's what the `-v` flag is for (verbose output)